# PostgreSQL last inserted ID not auto-increment typescript sequelize

Tags: node.js, typescript, postgresql, sequelize.js

User(
id :number ,
name : string pk)

How can I get the biggest latest id to insert a new one? The objective is to take the previous id and add a value but the id is not auto-increment. I was thinking about making a query to get the latest id but I hope there may be other optimized suggestion

thanks

Comment: You should define it as an `identity` (or at least `serial`) column.

Comment: I can't define it as a serial nor as identity because it shouldn't be auto-increment. any clue?

Comment: You can create a sequence in PostgreSQL and use it as a default value. In Sequelize you should indicate `autoIncrement: true`

Comment: Taking the previous id (a query to get the latest id) and adding a value is a bad idea because of MVCC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do what you want. But just because you can do something does not mean you should. I repeat you should use a serial or identity. @Stefanov.sm is corrent in a MVCC environment this is a very bad idea; because it is a **virtual guarantee** you will get a duplicate at some point.  
One way to get this is to write a function to do the insert. This function get the MAX(ID) + an increment. It also handles the duplicate error and retries the insert if needed.

```
create or replace 
function establish_user (user_name_in text ) 
 returns integer 
language plpgsql
as $$
declare
   k_id_inc    constant integer := 1;  
   l_id        integer;  
   l_inserted  boolean = false; 
begin 
    select coalesce(max(id) + k_id_inc)    
      into l_id 
      from users;
    
    while not l_inserted
    loop
        begin 
            insert into users (id, name) 
                 values (l_id, user_name_in);
                 
            l_inserted  = true; 
        exception 
            when others then 
               if sqlstate != '23505' 
               or sqlerrm not like '%users_id_uk%'
               then 
                   raise;
               else
                   l_id = l_id + 1;
               end if;
        end;  
    end loop; 

    return l_id; 
end;
$$;
```

See [Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=6b5e05e0719079f56c1af8f9f6693b25) here.